# Is it possible to use js script with laravel crontab?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cron, jspdf

I am suposed to make report scheduling in Laravel. Let's say that I want to send a pdf file to a list of emails that I get from my database every morning. I have written a command that calls a function from a controller, and the function returns a view where I have written a script.

Rather than using snappy or any other php libraries, I would like to do the report in jspdf. In the script I would pass the generated data via ajax back to controller and save the file in storage.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          var doc = new jsPDF();
          doc.text('text', 80, 10);
          var pdf = btoa(doc.output());
          $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : '*',
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            },
            url: url,
            data: {data: pdf},
          }).done(function(data){
             console.log(data);
          });
    });
</script>
```

Then in the controller I would do this:

```
public function data(Request $request)
{

      $data = base64_decode($request->data);
      \Storage::put('app/public', $data);

}
```

Is there any way in which I could force my javascript to be loaded when my crontab is called?

Comment: No, this won't work as you expect. Javascript cannot be executed via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a NodeJS expert but if you issue relies on a PDF, you certainly could do the same  in a NodeJS script and then call this script from your cron

Answer (score 0):

No, because your JavaScript is client sided, it cannot be called on the server. Not without making a Node.js script to generate your PDF.

Alternatively, you could look into some PHP PDF generation packages and then create [an artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#writing-commands) and [setup a cron job](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) and make your PDF be generated on the server side.